# No such file or directory: Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

[image: Error Report]

I am currently trying to implement AdMob into my project. I am currently getting the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" Can someone please take a look at my error report and tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Delete your derived data, restart your XCode, Clean and Build your project.

Comment: That did not work.